# Regular expression help

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, gsub

I am currently doing a bunch of processing on a string using regular expressions  with `gsub()` but I'm chaining them quite heavily which is starting to get messy. Can you help me construct a single regex for the following:

```
string.gsub(/\.com/,'').gsub(/\./,'').gsub(/&/,'and').gsub(' ','-').gsub("'",'').gsub(",",'').gsub(":",'').gsub("#39;",'').gsub("*",'').gsub("amp;",'')
```

Basically the above removes the following:

- .com
- .
- ,
- :
- *
- switches '&' for 'and'
- switches ' ' for '-'
- switches ' for ''

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the ones that remove characters:

```
string.gsub(/\.com|[.,:*]/,'')
```

The pipe `|` means "or". The right side of the or is a character class; it means "one of these characters".

Comment: Nice... Knew it would be simple!

Answer (score 1):

A translation table is more scalable as you add more options:

```
translations = Hash.new
translations['.com'] = ''
translations['&'] = 'and'
...

translations.each{ |from, to| string.gsub from, to }
```

Comment: +1 for this answer, I wouldn't do this but it's interesting thanks

Comment: you can actually pass the Hash to gsub, from the docs "If the second argument is a Hash, and the matched text is one of its keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string.", so string.gsub( from, translations ) will do the same.

Comment: @iain: That's not the same, `String#gsub(pattern, hash)` looks for a key that matches the pattern and replaces it with the value. It's not really useful in this case, but it would be for something like `string.gsub /\..+/, '.cmo' => '.com', '.ogr' => '.org'`

Answer (score 0):

Building on Tim's answer:

You can pass a block to `String.gsub`, so you could combine them all, if you wanted:

```
string.gsub(/\.com|[.,:*& ']/) do |sub|
    case(sub)
    when '&'
        'and'
    when ' '
        '-'
    else
        ''
    end
end
```

Or, building off echoback's answer, you could use a translation hash in the block (you may need to call `translations.default = ''` to get this working):

```
string.gsub(/\.com|[.,:*& ']/) {|sub| translations[sub]}
```

The biggest perk of using a block is only having one call to `gsub` (not the fastest function ever).

Hope this helps!